# Quelles phrase (parmi celles citées dans les détails) sont bien exprimées?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation

Pendant ma scolarité au primaire, j’ai eu besoin d’un accompagnement individualisé. (Ici c’est la disposition de « au primaire » qui me laisse perplexe).

Pendant ma scolarité au primaire, j’ai été accompagné par un spécialiste des difficultés scolaires et des troubles de l’apprentissage. (Ici c’est la tournure « accompagné par » qui me rend hésitant, i.e la voix passive)

Pendant ma scolarité au primaire, j’ai été suivi par un spécialiste des difficultés scolaires et des troubles de l’apprentissage. (Encore ici c’est la voix passive qui me fait douter, c-à-d ce qui suit le participe passé).

Est-ce que toutes ces phrases sont bien écrites? N’hésitez pas à me présenter d’autres formulations plus élégantes qui pourraient vous traverser l’esprit.

Merci!

Comment: We are not a text translation or proofreading service.  If you're asking about the correctness of a sentence, tell us which specific word or construction you are unsure about.

Comment: Traductions et corrections de texte ne sont pas faites par les utilisateurs du présent site. Si la demande est à propos de l'exactitude d'une phrase, dites-nous quel mot ou quelle construction vous fait douter.

Comment: Ces informations se trouvent entre parenthèses...

Comment: À mon sens je ne peux être plus clair, la voix passive me fait hésiter dans deux des phrases citées dans les détails, puis dans la mesure du possible j’aimerais qu’on me présente d’autres formulations afin d’élargir le cercle de mes connaissances en matière de tournure.

Comment: Oui, mais il ne s'agit pas d'une seule phrase ; il y en a quatre. D'après ce que je crois comprendre, il ne peut s'agir que d'une seule phrase par question. De toutes façon vous aurez plus de chances d'obtenir plus de formulations alternatives si vous ne présentez qu'une phrase par question.

Comment: Si le fait que la présentation des difficultés auquel je fais face dans les deux premières phrases soit absentes vous dérange, n’en faites pas cas et porter tout simplement votre attention sur celles qui ont les informations que vous demandez.

Comment: Je viens de voir ton dernier commentaire, j’étais en train d’en rédiger un de mon côté aussi. En réponse à ce dernier, message bien reçu LPH!

Comment: Rien, ou peu me dérange personnellement, et j'admettrais plus de possibilités si j'avais le pouvoir de le faire, mais je ne l'ai pas et tout ce que je fais c'est essayer de faire marcher les choses comme les principes écrits l'expliquent.

Comment: J’en suis maintenant conscient et je comprends votre décision.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118131/discussion-between-user25275-and-lph).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I** La locution « pendant ma scolarité au primaire » semble une possibilité acceptable ; on peut peut-être lui préférer cette locution que l'on trouve au [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/scolarit%C3%A9).

- pendant ma **scolarité primaire**

**II (III)** La voix passive est acceptable mais on peut utiliser une tournure à la voix active qui pourrait paraitre plus expressive. (« suivi » ou « accompagné » sont plus ou moins équivalents et donc la troisième phrase n'apporte rien.)

- Pendant ma scolarité  primaire, j’ai eu l'appui d'un accompagnement par des spécialistes des difficultés scolaires et des troubles de l’apprentissage.

Answer (score 0):

Voici deux propositions qui me semblent plus « naturelles » :

> Quand j'étais à l'école primaire, j’ai eu besoin d’un accompagnement personnalisé.

Pour coller à la terminologie utilisée par l'éducation nationale, je préfère *personnalisé* qui concerne les troubles de l'apprentissage qu'*individualisé* qui se rapporte plutôt aux pathologies chroniques, intolérances alimentaires, allergies.
Voir [Mettre en œuvre un plan d'accompagnement personnalisé](https://eduscol.education.fr/1214/mettre-en-oeuvre-un-plan-d-accompagnement-personnalise).

> Quand j'étais à l'école primaire, j’ai été suivi par un spécialiste des troubles de l’apprentissage et de l'accompagnement d'élèves en difficulté.